# mobile input number without triggering the digit keyboard

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

In my mobile application I would like to provide an efficient way to enter digit but without triggering the digit keyboard...
In my idea I would like to display 2 big digits and slide on it in order to increase/decrease the value

a bit like the 2 last left items [that http://media.mediatemple.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/mobile-input-type-date_mini1.jpg](http://media.mediatemple.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/mobile-input-type-date_mini1.jpg)
I didn't find something that fits my needs in polymer element core/paper.
I saw that [paper slider](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-slider)
is great for little value but greater than 20 it's not easy to use

Do you guys know a lib or something ? thank you !

#### update

to be more precise, < input type="time"> is what I would like in terms of design :)

Comment: make it! :) That's kind of the point of polymer too! Pick the closest thing that exists in paper and customise it? The put it back out on pub

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this component](https://github.com/Syncofy/calendar-date-picker) it's pretty good and it works well with the latest version of polymer (0.5.1)

It fits [Google's material design specifications](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/pickers.html).

I have used it after some modifications.

Here is a live [demo](http://syncofy.github.io/calendar-date-picker/).